# Formatar string ou float para moeda

Tags: javascript, jquery

Andei pesquisando a respeito mas não achei uma solução. Tenho por exemplo um float: **2087500**, quero deixa da seguinte forma ***U$ 20,875.00***.

Achei vários métodos de passar float para moeda mas todos tem um ponto (.) antes dos dois últimos dígitos para poder funcionar, assim **20875.00**. Tentei usar ***replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ".$1")*** para colocar esse ponto mas ele só é adicionado em String. E como disse, as funções que achei funcionam apenas com float.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com uma solução funcional por favor.

Comment: Os ultimos 2 numeros são casa decimais?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria melhor utilizar função [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) do objeto [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl), ela facilita a formatação de números conforme o idioma, exemplo:

```js
//Instanciando o objeto
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});
//pega o valor no campo e transforma em float
var valor = parseFloat(document.getElementById("moeda").value);
/*FORMATA CONFORME CONFIGURAÇÕES DEFINIDAS NO formatter*/
var formatado = formatter.format(valor); 
//Coloca o valor formatado no campo resultado
document.getElementById("resultado").value = formatado;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="moeda" value="20875.00">
<input type="text" id="resultado" value="">
```

```js
//Instanciando o objeto
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'BRL',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});
//pega o valor no campo e transforma em float
var valor = parseFloat(document.getElementById("moeda").value);
/*FORMATA CONFORME CONFIGURAÇÕES DEFINIDAS NO formatter*/
var formatado = formatter.format(valor); 
//Coloca o valor formatado no campo resultado
document.getElementById("resultado").value = formatado;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="moeda" value="20875.00">
<input type="text" id="resultado" value="">
```

OBS: Para utilizar desta forma, tanto a `string` quanto o `float` que pretende formatar deve conter o valor correto com casas decimais, por exemplo:

> 1 = $1.00
>   1.0 = $1.00
>   10 = $10.00

Answer (score 2):

Funções com e sem input.

```js
var mask = {
   money: function() {
      var el = this
      ,exec = function(v) {
         v = v.replace(/\D/g,"");
         v = new String(Number(v));
         var len = v.length;
         if (1== len)
            v = v.replace(/(\d)/,"0,0$1");
         else if (2 == len)
            v = v.replace(/(\d)/,"0,$1");
         else if (len > 2) {
            v = v.replace(/(\d{2})$/,',$1');
            if (len > 5) {
               var x = len - 5
               ,er = new RegExp('(\\d{'+x+'})(\\d)');
               v = v.replace(er,'$1.$2');
            }
         }
         return v;
      };
      setTimeout(function(){
         el.value = exec(el.value);
      },1);
   }
}

$(function(){
   $('input').bind('keypress',mask.money)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  value=""/>
```

```js
function mascara(v) {
  v = v.replace(/\D/g,"");
  v = new String(Number(v));
  var len = v.length;
  if (1== len)
    v = v.replace(/(\d)/,"0,0$1");
  else if (2 == len)
    v = v.replace(/(\d)/,"0,$1");
  else if (len > 2) {
    v = v.replace(/(\d{2})$/,',$1');
  if (len > 5) {
  var x = len - 5
  ,er = new RegExp('(\\d{'+x+'})(\\d)');
  v = v.replace(er,'$1.$2');
  }
}
return v;
}
console.log(mascara('2087500'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No caso eu já tenho o valor em uma variável, precisaria aplicar a mascara e $("#boxValorTotal4").text(valorComMascara); como poderia aplicar? Isso sem click nem nada do tipo, quando a pagina carrega ele já faz isso.

Comment: Alterei a função para passar apenas um valor e ela colocar a mascara.

Comment: Funcionou, mas se for necessário aplicar a mascara em números acima de 1 milhão ele já não pontua corretamente. Ex: 20800.075,00

Comment: Realmente, fiz exatamente pra tua pergunta kk, tem como você ir modificando de acordo com suas necessidades em casas.

Comment: Tendi, deu uma olhada aqui e caiu a ficha rsrs, obg mesmo

Answer (score 2):

apenas dividir por 100 não seria o suficiente?

```js
var intl = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", { 
  style: "currency", 
  currency: "USD"
});
var valor = 2087500;
var moeda = intl.format((valor / 100));
console.log(valor, moeda);
```